# SQL Query of Using Functions - How to get MAXIMUM Count of the list

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I query for the MAXIMUM COUNT Number of transaction...
My code is as follows:

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(customer_id)
FROM rental
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING MAX(COUNT(customer_id)); //I need to get the MAXIMUM COUNT of the list
```

Comment: I think we need some sample data if none of the posted answers are working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since more than one customer can have the same Maximum of the count you should do as follows

```
SELECT customer_id, 
       COUNT(customer_id) AS customerrowcount 
FROM   rental 
GROUP  BY customer_id 
HAVING COUNT(customer_id) = (SELECT COUNT(customer_id) 
                             FROM   rental 
                             GROUP  BY customer_id 
                             ORDER  BY COUNT(customer_id) DESC 
                             LIMIT  1)
```

However if you're ok with an arbitrary customer being selected than you should use rsbarro's answer

Comment: So how can i resolve the issue of having a customer with the same MAXIMUM account

Comment: You'll get two customers back. You'll need to find out from your users who to resolve ties.

Comment: @ConradFrix  Is this also possible by not using limit ?

Comment: @Achyut sure you could use max to determine what the value of the largest count is. e.g. `having count(customer_id) = (select max(k) from (select count(customer_id) k from rental group by customer_id) t)`

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the `customer_id` with largest number of rows in the `rental` table, you could use:

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(customer_id) as CustomerRowCount
FROM rental
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY COUNT(customer_id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The above query will count all of the records for each customer_id, sort them in descending order, and then select only the top row. The maximum count for a customer will be present in `CustomerRowCount`.

**EDIT**
Conrad brought up the point that two or more `customer_id`'s may have the same number of records. If the business requirement is that multiple records should be returned in this case, then his query will give you the result you're looking for. If only one record should be returned, then a simple, consistent way to break ties would just be to take the user with the lowest `customer_id`. To do that, you can just change the ORDER BY statement to:

```
ORDER BY COUNT(customer_id) DESC, customer_id
```

Comment: I need to know the MAXimum COUNT

Comment: @newbie Sorry, I'm not understanding what you're looking for. If someone hasn't already figured it out, could you update your question with some sample data?

Comment: @newbie both queries provide the maximum count. or the largest count for a specific customer.  Hence the reason for ordering by the count in decending order then selecting the top row.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT customer_id, MAX(COUNT(customer_id))
FROM rental
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

or

```
SELECT top 1 customer_id, COUNT(customer_id)
FROM rental
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY COUNT(customer_id) DESC
```

Comment: I think you're missing a DESC on the ORDER BY for the second query. =]

Answer (score 2):

Query for MySQL

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM (SELECT 
        customer_id, 
        COUNT(customer_id) AS CountOfCustomer
      FROM rental
      GROUP BY customer_id) q1
ORDER BY CountOfCustomer DESC
LIMIT 1
```