# multiple highest records mysql

Tags: mysql, max

there are two rows with highest values of 5 but the query below only returns last highest record... how can i get all rows with highest value of members??

can i use max is where clause plz help?

```
SELECT teamcode,MAX(member) AS members FROM(
    SELECT t.`teamcode` AS teamcode,
    COUNT(*) AS member
    FROM `users` u
    JOIN teams t
    ON u.teamcode=t.tm_id
    GROUP BY `teamcode`
) AS maxcount
```

How to get all highest values?

Comment: Hello and welcome to strackoverflow. I've edited your post to remove the greetings as in SO you will primarily say "thank you" by [voting / accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Give us more information (table structure with example data on sql friddle) you can use a deliverd table to fetch the results you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, since you only want to count using the teamcode: you won't need to use a `JOIN`! 
You do, however, need a helper table.

```
  SELECT teamcode,
         COUNT(*) as members
    FROM users
GROUP BY teamcode
  HAVING COUNT(*) = (   SELECT COUNT(*)
                          FROM users
                      GROUP BY teamcode
                      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                         LIMIT 1             );
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5faa/41/0), if you'd like.

Used references:
[SQL Query of Using Functions - How to get MAXIMUM Count of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725237/sql-query-of-using-functions-how-to-get-maximum-count-of-the-list)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You would probably be better off getting the rows with max value from the WHERE clause, e.g.,:

`WHERE member = MAX(member)`
instead of trying to do that in the SELECT clause.</strike>

EDIT:
I'm stretching my knowledge of SQL a bit here, but try this:

`SELECT teamcode, member

FROM(
SELECT t.'teamcode' AS teamcode, COUNT(*) AS member
FROM 'users' u JOIN teams t ON u.teamcode = t.tm_id
GROUP BY 'teamcode'
HAVING member = MAX(member)
) AS maxcount`

Comment: Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'member' in 'where clause'

Comment: Are you sure? Could you please give a complete query as this syntax would most probably result in "Invalid use of group function"...

Comment: SELECT t.`teamcode` AS teamcode,
 COUNT(*) AS member
 FROM `users` u
 JOIN teams t
 ON u.teamcode=t.tm_id
 WHERE member = MAX(member)
 GROUP BY `teamcode`

Comment: I edited my answer, after doing a bit more research. See above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want not only the max value in your query, It's better to use GROUP BY.

```
SELECT teamcode,MAX(member) AS members FROM(
    SELECT t.`teamcode` AS teamcode,
    COUNT(*) AS member
    FROM `users` u
    JOIN teams t
    ON u.teamcode=t.tm_id
    GROUP BY `teamcode`
) AS maxcount
GROUP BY teamcode
```

And if you want two the five highest values, you should use the clause "LIMIT".